# "Shiv and Parvati's son" or "Shiv's and Parvati's son"?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

I'm writing a story about Lord Ganesh; which of the following is more correct?

> Ganesh claimed to be Shiv and Parvati's son.

> Ganesh claimed to be Shiv's and Parvati's son.

Comment: Neither is more 'correct'; Some style guides suggest one single apostrophe at the end of a list of linked nouns, thus _Shiv and Parvati's son_, and separate ones if the 'possession is not shared, thus _London's and Delhi's railway systems_. However even educated native speakers of English may feel insecure when confronting a compound possessive, and very often opt for separate possessives ('_Shiv's and Parvati's son_') which  will never be considered 'wrong', but may be called 'clumsy' by some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the British Council [website](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/a1-a2-grammar/possessive-s). If something belongs to more than one person, and we give a list of names, the 's comes after the last name in the list.

Liam is Anne and Gary's son.

So, your first sentence is correct.

However, you can add 's to two (or more) people if two (or more) things belong to them.
Compare:

> This is Anne and Gary's **car**. (They have **one** car.)

and

> These are Anne's and Gary's **cars**. (Each of them has one (maybe more) separate car.)